# Extract text from XML, but file has duplicated node-names

Tags: r, xml

Im trying to import some data from an XML-file into an R data.frame.
While I'm pretty experienced with R, I have never worked with an XML before, so all this is pretty new to me and I feel a little lost.

A sample of the XML is provided below:

```
<ArchivedIncident ID="100">
    <attributes>
        <entry>
            <key>TEST1</key>
            <value>
                <type>S</type>
                <value/>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>TEST2</key>
            <value>
                <type>S</type>
                <value>12</value>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>TEST3</key>
            <value>
                <type>T</type>
                <value>A</value>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>TEST4</key>
            <value>
                <type>S</type>
                <value/>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </attributes>
</ArchivedIncident>
<ArchivedIncident ID="101">
    <attributes>
        <entry>
            <key>TEST1</key>
            <value>
                <type>S</type>
                <value>BLAH</value>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>TEST2</key>
            <value>
                <type>S</type>
                <value/>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>TEST3</key>
            <value>
                <type>T</type>
                <value/>
            </value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>TEST4</key>
            <value>
                <type>S</type>
                <value/>
            </value>
        </entry>
    </attributes>
</ArchivedIncident>
```

What I like to accomplish, is an R-data.frame that looks like this:

```
ID     TEST1    TEST2    TEST3    TEST4
100    NA       12       A        NA
101    BLAH     NA       NA       NA
```

What I have come up with so far:

Using the xml2 package, I can read the ID's using:

```
require(xml2)
doc <- read_xml("./data/file.xml")
df <- data.frame( 
  ID = xml_attr( xml_find_all( doc, ".//ArchivedIncident" ), "ID" )
  )
```

So far so good, but now I'm lost how to extract the rest. There are multiple nodes, all named "entry", "value" and "type". How can I extract the text from the  (for use as a column name), and the value for this key (which is the  following after  of that .

Complicating factor, is that not every  has a value. I would like to insert a "NA" for the empty values.
In another situation, I was able to use a custom function for this, but I'm not sure (since I don't know how to extract the right text) if this will work here.

```
L <- xml_find_all(doc, ".//ArchivedIncident")
FindAllValues <- function(node){
    tmp <- lapply(L, xml_find_all, paste0(".//", node))
    tmp <- lapply(tmp, xml_text)
    tmp[!sapply(tmp, function(y) length(y == 0))] <- NA
    return(tmp)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

doc <- read_xml("file.xml")

xml_find_all(doc, ".//ArchivedIncident") %>% # iterate over each incident
  map_df(~{
    set_names(
      xml_find_all(.x, ".//value/value") %>% xml_text(), # get entry values
      xml_find_all(.x, ".//key") %>% xml_text()          # get entry keys (column names)
    ) %>% 
      as.list() %>%                                      # turn named vector to list
      flatten_df() %>%                                   # and list to df
      mutate(ID = xml_attr(.x, "ID"))                    # add id
  }) %>%
  type_convert() %>% # let R convert the values for you
  select(ID, everything()) # get it in the order you likely want
## # A tibble: 2 x 5
##      ID TEST1 TEST2 TEST3 TEST4
##   <int> <chr> <int> <chr> <chr>
## 1   100  <NA>    12     A  <NA>
## 2   101  BLAH    NA  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: That works perfectly, also for my 'real' XML-data!! Thank you very much for your readable solution. The comments are also very helpful!

Comment: How could we modify the code above if for example we wanted "key", "type" and "value as the column names and then "TEST1", "S", "BLAH" to under each of the column